# .getResponse Code Throwing IOException on a Valid URL

Tags: java, http, methods, web-crawler, httpresponse

I'm building a webcrawler and have a method to check for bad link. At one point I am trying to get the HTTP response code to determine if it is valid or not. despite handing it a valid URL (opened it in a browser just fine) it still returns that it isn't valid. Here is the code:

```
public static boolean isBrokenLink(URL baseURL, String theHREF) {
        boolean isBroken = false;
        if (baseURL == null) {
            try {
                baseURL = new URL("HTTP", "cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/", theHREF);
                System.out.println(baseURL);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                isBroken = true;
                //e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        try {
            URLConnection con = baseURL.openConnection();
            HttpURLConnection httpProtocol = (HttpURLConnection) con;
            System.out.println(httpProtocol.getResponseCode());
            if (httpProtocol.getResponseCode() != 200 && httpProtocol.getResponseCode() == -1) {
                isBroken = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            isBroken = true;
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return isBroken;
    }   
            }
```

And [here](http://cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/page2.htm) is the URL I'm passing it. isBroken is the boolean that is being returned. I passing baseURL as null and theHREF as a relative link (page2.htm). I'm printing out the URL after creating it from the string. Thanks for any help!
Here is the error:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:178)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:996)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:850)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1300)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468)
    at edu.uwec.cs.carpenne.webcrawler.Webcrawler.isBrokenLink(Webcrawler.java:106)
    at edu.uwec.cs.carpenne.webcrawler.Webcrawler.main(Webcrawler.java:181)
```

Comment: Might want to post that `IOException` stack trace.

Comment: Let's see how you create your `baseURL`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception tells us, that it is using the hostname and the local part as the (unknown) host. This looks like you have constructing the URL incorrectly. Maybe you forgot to use `http://` prefix or used the wrong getters? You can debug it by calling `baseURL.getHost()`, `baseURL.getPath()` and `baseURL.getProtocol()` to see if it returns `cs.uwec.edu` and `/~steve...` and `http`.

I just noticed you added the baseURL with `new URL("HTTP", "cs.uwec.edu/~stevende/cs145testpages/", theHREF)` this is wrong, you need to use [`new URL("http", "cs.uwec.edu", 80, "/~stevende/cs145testpages/#"+theHREF)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String%29). You can however typically skip the anchor/ref, as it will not transmitted to the server.

You can also use the single argument constructor [`new URL("http://cs.uwec.edu//~stevende/cs145testpages/")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#URL%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: Your solution worked! I'm still confused as why mine was wrong. I followed what I found in the API.

Comment: There are multiple ways to construct a URL and you need to pay attention to what the parameters are named. If the second string parameter is named "host" you may only pass a host name in. The reason for this is that internally a URL is not a single string but multiple fields (and one of them is for the hostname). the simplest method is to use `new URL("http://host/path")` as it will try to parse the string and separate it. Only this version splits the segments (often correctly). If you have the different components in variables, it is better to specify them directly to avoid the parsing.